# duplicates in a JSON file based on two attributes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a JSON file and that is a nested JSON. I would like to remove duplicates based on two keys.

JSON example:

```
"books": [
{
            "id": "1",
            "story": {
                "title": "Lonely lion"
            },
            "description": [
                {
                    "release": false,
                    "author": [
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "main": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Jeroge",
                            "main": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Peter",
                            "main": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    {
            "id": "2",
            "story": {
                "title": "Lonely lion"
            },
            "description": [
                {
                    "release": false,
                    "author": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jeroge",
                            "main": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Peter",
                            "main": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "main": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
{
            "id": "3",
            "story": {
                "title": "Lonely lion"
            },
            "description": [
                {
                    "release": false,
                    "author": [
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "main": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Jeroge",
                            "main": 0
                        }
                        
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

Here I try to match the title and author name. For example, for id 1 and id 2 are duplicates( as the title is same and author names are also same(the author sequence doesn't matter and no need to consider the main attributes). So, in the output JSON only id:1 or id:2 will remain with id:3. In the final output I need two file.

```
Output_JSON:
"books": [
{
            "id": "1",
            "story": {
                "title": "Lonely lion"
            },
            "description": [
                {
                    "release": false,
                    "author": [
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "main": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Jeroge",
                            "main": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Peter",
                            "main": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
 
{
            "id": "3",
            "story": {
                "title": "Lonely lion"
            },
            "description": [
                {
                    "release": false,
                    "author": [
                        {
                            "name": "John",
                            "main": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Jeroge",
                            "main": 0
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

```
duplicatedID.csv:

1-2
```

The following method I tried but it is not giving correct results:

```
list= []
duplicate_Id = []
for data in (json_data['books'])[:]:   
    
    elements= []
    id = data['id']
    title = data['story']['title']
    elements.append(title)
    for i in (data['description'][0]['author']):
        name = (i['name'])
        elements.append(name)
    
   if not list:
        list.append(elements)
    
    
    else:
        for j in list:
            if set(elements) == set(j):
                duplicate_Id.append(id)
                elements = []
```

Comment: How have you tried solving this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to:

- Get the groups identified by some function that collects duplicates.
- Then return the first entry of each group, ensuring no duplicates.
- Define the key function as the sorted list of authors and. As the list of authors is by definition the unique key, but may appear in any order.

```
import json
from itertools import groupby

j = json.load(books)


def transform(books):
    groups = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(books, key=getAuthors)]
    return [group[0] for group in groups]

def getAuthors(book):
    authors = book['description'][0]['author']
    return sorted([author['name'] for author in authors])

print(transform(j['books']))
```

If we wanted to get the duplicates, then we do the same computation, but return any sublist with `length > 1` as this is by our definition duplicated data.

```
def transform(books):
    groups = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(books, key=getAuthors)]
    return [group for group in groups if len(group) > 1]
```

Where `j['books']` is the JSON you gave enclosed in an object.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to get the list which are same? for example here id 1 and id 2 are same

Comment: Most things are possible, and that certainly is. groupby turns a list into a list of lists, where the nested lists are elements grouped by some key. In our case, that key is the sorted list of author names. See the revised answer @sanazz